# Ordering by columns not working on many columns in Tag Synonyms page of SOes

Tags: bug, status-review, tag-synonyms, spanish-stackoverflow

In the [Tag Synonyms page of Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), the ordering by many of the filters does not work. The only one which does work is the first column, 'Sinónimo' (*Synonym*), while 'Destino' (*Target*) sometimes does. On the rest, clicking on a column arrow triggers an action, but no ordering is performed on that concept.

> [image]

In the rest of Stack Overflows, they all work (I provide a link so you can go and click randomly to see them in motion):

- SO: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms
- SOpt: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms
- SOja: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms
- SOru: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: This error continues... and it has been reported for a long time and no one said anything about it.